# Interpretation of having a significant difference but no correlation between variables

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have data that includes a specific metric for which I want to investigate if it is having a (causal) relation with the other metrics. When I check the correlations (Pearson and Kendall) I find no correlation between the target metric and the others.
However, if I split the data into two groups based on the target metric I do find a significant difference in the mean values of the other metrics. (I checked using Welch test since Levene check showed significant difference in variance)

Somehow I have a hard time wrapping my head around this conceptually. Does this make sense or is there something going wrong in my calculations or am I not allowed to do specific actions?
If there is a confound variable influencing both my target metric and the others, wouldn't that show as a correlation as well or could this be the cause of what I'm observing?

Comment: No significant correlation, or a correlation of 0? If you mean a correlation of zero, you're right, this shouldn't happen, and it's most likely a coding error, or something isn't as you've described. Having you tried plotting your target metric against the others? And how are you doing the splitting?

Comment: Can you add some concept **What are** your metrics? Sample size? ... this is very abstract ...

Comment: thanks for the comments. It's behavioral data and the target metric is something that will 'happen' to the user. Let's say the target metric is experiencing rain. My data consists of users doing activities during the day and how many times they've encountered rain. I'm splitting based on rain >0 and try to see if people abandon/do less of their activities. The difference in groups could be easily explained the other way around; if you do more you have a higher chance of encountering rain. However, I still would expect a correlation then ?
Correlations are not 0, but something like 0,008

Comment: just occured to me this could be due to the presence of outliers in one group perhaps? This would (significantly) shift the mean while not resulting in correlation?